# Threads.maximum value in the array

Tags: multithreading, perl

Actually, let's say, 2 thread started. And an array of 5 elements, all calculations are carried out 1 trade. 2 appears and dies for lack of work. Or, if you specify 9999 elements, then he wakes up in the last 30-50 items. It seems to me that he does not really multithreaded.

```
#! usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;
use  warnings;
use  5.010;
use threads;
use threads::shared;
use Data::Dumper;

my $n=0;

my $max:shared=0;
my @threads;
my $shr:shared=0;
say "Enter the number of threads";
my $threads=<stdin>;
my @pack;

#Заполняем массив
say "Enter the number of array elements";
my $c=<stdin>;
for (my $i=0;$i<$c;$i++){
    my $r= int rand 999;
    @pack=(@pack,$r);
                        }
                         say  @pack;

# Создаём нужное количество потоков
for my $t (1..$threads) {
    push @threads,threads->create(\&find,$t);
                        }
# Дожидаемся окончания работы всех потоков
for my  $t (@threads){ $t->join();}

sub find {
    # Номер текущего потока
    my $num= shift;
    say "+Thread $num started";

    while($n<=$#pack){
        # Распределяем элементы по потокам
        lock($shr);#lock ($max);
        my $stg=1+$shr++;

        # Если элементы закончились, прерываем работу
        if ($stg>=$#pack+2) {
            say "-Thread $num done. \n";
            return;}


        if($max<$pack[$n]){$max=$pack[$n];}
        say "Thread: $num \tStage: $stg  \tMax: $max";
        $n++;
        sleep 1+int rand (3);       
             }
        }
```

Comment: You will probably want to open an account on http://ru.stackoverflow.com, since this site is solely for English questions.

Comment: The entire work code of the thread is in a block in which `lock($shr)` is obtained, preventing more than one thread from doing any work.

Comment: ohh, god..Thank you!)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The entire work code of the thread is in a block in which `lock($shr)` is obtained, preventing more than one thread from doing any work.

---

It sounds like you have a large array, and you want worker threads to process parts of that large array.

The only time the thread needs to be synchronized is when grabbing work, and when updating the results.

Note that you need to lock the array when you are accessing it, but you can't keep it lock when you are working, so you'll need to copy to work unit into a thread-local variable.

The follow finds the sum of all elements of an array.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature qw( say );

use threads;
use threads::shared;

use List::Util qw( sum );

# This is where the real work is done.
# Notice how it there's no thread-related code in it
# and how it doesn't use any shared variables.
sub work {
    sleep(1+rand(3));
    return sum(@_);
}

{
    @ARGV == 3
        or die("usage\n");

    my ($data_size, $num_threads, $chunk_size) = @ARGV;

    my $next :shared = 0;
    my @data :shared;
    my $sum  :shared;

    for (1..$data_size) {
        push @data, int(rand(9999));
    }

    say "Without threads: ", sum @data;

    for my $t (1..$num_threads) {
        async {
            say sprintf("[%s]: Worker started.", threads->tid);
            LOOP: while (1) {
                # Grab work.
                my @local_data;
                {
                    lock $next;
                    last LOOP if $next >= @data;

                    my $new_next = $next + $chunk_size;
                    $new_next = @data if $new_next > @data;

                    say sprintf("[%s] Processing %s..%s", threads->tid, $next, $new_next-1);
                    @local_data = @data[$next .. $new_next-1];
                    $next = $new_next;
                }

                my $local_sum = work(@local_data);    

                # Update results.
                { lock $sum; $sum += $local_sum; }
            }
            say sprintf("[%s] done.", threads->tid)
        };
    }

    $_->join for threads->list;

    say "With threads: $sum";
}
```

Output:

```
$ ./a 125 3 20
Without threads: 577556
[1]: Worker started.
[1] Processing 0..19
[2]: Worker started.
[2] Processing 20..39
[3]: Worker started.
[3] Processing 40..59
[2] Processing 60..79
[1] Processing 80..99
[3] Processing 100..119
[1] Processing 120..124
[2] done.
[1] done.
[3] done.
With threads: 577556
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [`Thread::Queue`](http://perldoc.perl.org/Thread/Queue.html) to deliver *jobs* or *work items* to the threads: Split the `@data` into chunks and push references to copies of them into such a queue. The threads then `dequeue` these references, dereference them, sum them up, and add the (partial) result to the global `$sum`. After pushing the *work items* to the queue you have to insert as many "undefs" as there are threads so that each thread gets an "undef" in its `while` loop and stops processing.

Newer versions of `Thread::Queue` have a method `end()`. In your case it can be called from the main thread (instead of enqueueing `n` undefs) but the result is almost the same: the `dequeue` call in the threads will return the remaining items and then `undef` for each thread. I prefer enqueueing `undef` as it's more explicit (and doesn't depend on the actual version of `Threads::Queue`).

The code would then be:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use threads;
use threads::shared;
use Thread::Queue;
use List::Util;

my $sum : shared = 0;
my $jobs = Thread::Queue->new();

sub add_in_thread
{
    printf( "[%s] started\n", threads->tid() );
    while ( my $workitem = $jobs->dequeue() ) {
        printf( "[%s] Processing %d items\n", threads->tid(), scalar @{$workitem} );
        my $local_sum = List::Util::sum( @{$workitem} );
        { lock $sum; $sum += $local_sum; }
        sleep( 1 + rand(3) );
    }
    printf( "[%s] done\n", threads->tid() );
}

sub main
{
    my ( $data_size, $num_threads, $chunk_size ) = @ARGV;

    my @data = map { int( rand(9999) ) } ( 1 .. $data_size );

    print "Without threads: ", List::Util::sum(@data), "\n";

    # split @data into chunks and put references
    # of copies of them into the $jobs queue
    while ( my @chunk = splice( @data, 0, $chunk_size ) ) {
        $jobs->enqueue( [@chunk] );
    }

    # add 'undef' for each thread so it knows when to finish:
    $jobs->enqueue( (undef) x $num_threads );

    # start threads:
    threads->create('add_in_thread') foreach ( 1 .. $num_threads );

    # wait for them to finish:                        }
    $_->join() for threads->list();

    print "With threads:    $sum\n";

    return 0;
}

exit( main() );
```

Output for `./so17.pl 125 3 20`

```
Without threads: 623399
[1] started
[1] Processing 20 items
[2] started
[2] Processing 20 items
[3] started
[3] Processing 20 items
[1] Processing 20 items
[2] Processing 20 items
[3] Processing 20 items
[1] Processing 5 items
[2] done
[3] done
[1] done
With threads:    623399
```

---

You can also start the threads in advance. They will block at the `while` loop (actually at the `dequeue()` call) until something is in that queue. If it's `undef` (or some other *falsy* value) they will stop processing and end. Else they will process the item in that queue. The `Thread::Queue` will do all the locking and syncing. You could even set up a 2nd queue and have the threads push their results into it and make the main thread fetch the results from that 2nd result queue.

Comment: `->end` is more actually more explicitly. It says it right there in the name. It's also less error-prone, and useful in more situations. /// Also, you're creating the threads and filling up the queue in the wrong order. Get those threads going ASAP so they can start working ASAP. /// Finally, the whole point of the post you copied was that the worker should do anything thready stuff, *especially since that's what got the OP in trouble*. It's *far* better for the thread loop to be kept separate from the work routine.

Comment: I kept the array since I thought he might have wanted to update the array in his real code, but I would actually use Thread::Queue myself here (with the fixes I mentioned in the previous comment).

Comment: @ikegami `->end()` was introduced in T::Q 3.01 (aka Perl 5.18). I use T::Q quite longer and was used to enqueueing undefs. Also I misinterpreted `->end()` and wrongly thought it would make _one_ `dequeue()` call return _all_ remaining items at once. After re-reading the docs I totally agree that `->end()` should be preferred (if available). /// Separating worker from thread code would mean to move my `List::Util::sum(…);` line into a separate function (like your `work()`). Granted. /// After all, the intention of my post was to show T::Q in action. It's so elegant!

Comment: Thread::Queue can be installed form CPAN. Upgrading Perl to 5.18 is not necessary.